# how to fetch draft in android programmatically

Tags: android, sms

I want to fetch all draft in android phone.

I find a sample to get draft massages that use below address.

```
getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/canonical-address"), null, null, null, null);
```

I hadn't any result for below uri and i had an exception:

```
content://sms/draft
```

I've tested on android 5.1 and i had an `IIllegalException` i don't know what is wrong.

I've tested in LG G4(android 5.1) and Nexus 4 AVD(android 4.2.2)

How can i access to drafts columns in android and get body and number?

Is there any problem for android version?

Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information on your development environment and how you are testing (Emulator or phone)?

Comment: I've tested in LG G4(android 5.1) and Nexus 4 AVD(android 4.2.2)

Comment: The second URI - `content://sms/draft` - is what you want. Please post your stack trace.